# Where can you check how much Ether has been exploited / stolen from theDAO?

Tags: the-dao, dao

Is there a site where you can check how much Ether has been exploited/stolen from theDAO? So far I only know of the first attack, which was 3 million stolen, but I read more people are doing this same attack to drain theDAO. Where can one see the status of this drain?

Comment: Sorry. I nominated this question for reopening. Just ignore my reopen request. Thanks.

Comment: See http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6408/how-many-ethers-have-been-drained-through-the-recursive-call-attacks-on-the-dao