# What are the balances of The DAO and it's child DAOs on the Ethereum Classic chain?

Tags: the-dao, attacks, hardforks, balances, ethereum-classic

At the hard-fork block [#1,920,000](https://etherscan.io/block/1920090), the ETH balance from The DAO and it's child DAOs (which includes the balance from the extraBalance account) were transferred into the [Withdrawal contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0xbf4ed7b27f1d666546e30d74d50d173d20bca754#code).

What are the current The DAO and child DAO balances on the Ethereum Classic chain that did not undergo the hard-fork?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm using the same unmodified script from [How many ethers have been drained through the recursive call attacks on The DAO?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6408/how-many-ethers-have-been-drained-through-the-recursive-call-attacks-on-the-dao) to calculate the balance of The DAO and it's child DAOs.

For a finer categorisation of the different child DAOs, see the latest update from [How do I get a refund for my The DAO tokens that was split into a child DAO?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7299/how-do-i-get-a-refund-for-my-the-dao-tokens-that-was-split-into-a-child-dao). There are several child DAOs with innocent splitters AND malicious drainers.

Here is the data generated from the ETC chain @ 05:58 02/08/2016 GMT:

```
Type         #                      Balance                 ExtraBalance                       Tokens Address
---------- --- ---------------------------- ---------------------------- ---------------------------- ------------------------------------------
The DAO      0        63.178156790000000001         0.000000000089472700  1153816598.7024669647216797 0xbb9bc244d798123fde783fcc1c72d3bb8c189413
child DAO    1         0.110000142499690430         0.000000000000000000          11.0000142499690430 0xd4fe7bc31cedb7bfb8a345f31e668033056b2728
child DAO    4         0.008519214441755701         0.000000000000000000          79.8519214441755594 0x2c19c7f9ae8b751e37aeb2d93a699722395ae18f
child DAO    7       989.001281201758472346         0.000000000000000000       98900.1281201758538373 0x1975bd06d486162d5dc297798dfc41edd5d160a7
child DAO    8         0.000000000000090658         1.428573279216753537      202867.2384762869332917 0x319f70bab6845585f412ec7724b744fec6095c85
child DAO   10         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000       20500.6432347392910742 0x5c8536898fbb74fc7445814902fd08422eac56d0
child DAO   13         0.100000000000000000         0.018693039890011849      105482.6948358116351301 0x779543a0491a837ca36ce8c635d6154e3c4911a6
child DAO   14         0.000000000000000001         0.000000000000000000       74635.9658653056685580 0x5c6e67ccd5849c0d29219c4f95f1a7a93b3f5dc5
child DAO   16      1250.001619314659344457         0.000000000000000000      125000.1619314659328666 0x200450f06520bdd6c527622a273333384d870efb
child DAO   18         0.000000000854763543         0.000000000000000000     3457503.6590232858434319 0x6b0c4d41ba9ab8d8cfb5d379c69a612f2ced8ecb
child DAO   19         0.018387737083543350         0.000000000000000000     1686497.8387737083248794 0xd1ac8b1ef1b69ff51d1d401a476e7e612414f091
child DAO   20        10.000012954517274755         0.000000000000000000        1000.0012954517275148 0x51e0ddd9998364a2eb38588679f0d2c42653e4a6
child DAO   22         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000      240000.3009084016666748 0xf0b1aa0eb660754448a7937c022e30aa692fe0c5
child DAO   23         0.000000000000011277         0.000000000000000000        9999.8647723253125150 0x9f27daea7aca0aa0446220b98d028715e3bc803d
child DAO   26       100.000129545172747556         0.000000000000000000       10000.0129545172749204 0xd9aef3a1e38a39c16b31d1ace71bca8ef58d315b
child DAO   27        41.173345768012804300         0.000000000000000000        4117.3345768012804911 0x6f6704e5a10332af6672e50b3d9754dc460dfa4d
child DAO   28         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000       36738.0383063135377597 0x492ea3bb0f3315521c31f273e565b868fc090f17
child DAO   29         0.000000000000090010         0.000000000000000000     1583946.1690131428185850 0x9ea779f907f0b315b364b0cfc39a0fde5b02a416
child DAO   31         0.060000077727103648         0.000000000000000000           6.0000077727103651 0xcc34673c6c40e791051898567a1222daf90be287
child DAO   32         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000       10705.0138678107414307 0xe308bd1ac5fda103967359b2712dd89deffb7973
child DAO   33         0.000000000000000001         0.000000000000000000     1313899.0176146971061826 0xac1ecab32727358dba8962a0f3b261731aad9723
child DAO   34         0.054104538362875475         0.000000000000000000       26685.4104538362880703 0x440c59b325d2997a134c2c7c60a8c61611212bad
child DAO   35         2.236999142516500888         0.000000000000000000         223.6999142516500854 0x9c15b54878ba618f494b38f0ae7443db6af648ba
child DAO   36         0.027428797178668633         0.000000000000000000           2.7428797178668631 0x21c7fdb9ed8d291d79ffd82eb2c4356ec0d81241
child DAO   37        76.761842290232377901         0.000000000000000000        7676.1842290232380037 0x1ca6abd14d30affe533b24d7a21bff4c2d5e1f3b
child DAO   39         0.000000000000056186         0.000000000000000000      212183.7249362469301559 0x6131c42fa982e56929107413a9d526fd99405560
child DAO   41         0.000000000000000001         0.000000000000000000     1254878.3143344640266150 0x542a9515200d14b68e934e9830d91645a980dd7a
child DAO   44       250.000323862931868891         0.000000000000000000       25000.0323862931873009 0x782495b7b3355efb2833d56ecb34dc22ad7dfcc4
child DAO   45         0.000000000000000001         0.000000000000000000           0.0000000000000001 0x3ba4d81db016dc2890c81f3acec2454bff5aada5
child DAO   52         0.000006477258637377         0.000000000000000000         500.0006477258637574 0xe4ae1efdfc53b73893af49113d8694a057b9c0d1
child DAO   53         7.144077587762826223         0.000000000000000000         714.4077587762826624 0x0737a6b837f97f46ebade41b9bc3e1c509c85c53
child DAO   54         0.002585721648041229         0.000000000000000000      199600.2585721648065373 0x52c5317c848ba20c7504cb2c8052abd1fde29d03
child DAO   56         5.000006477258637377         0.000000000000000000         500.0006477258637574 0x5d2b2e6fcbe3b11d26b525e085ff818dae332479
child DAO   57         0.009900012824972102         0.000000000000000000           0.9900012824972102 0x057b56736d32b86616a10f619859c6cd6f59092a
Baddies     59         0.000000000000000011       285.714295714285714286   364240852.7612792849540710 0x304a554a310c7e546dfe434669c62820b7d83490
child DAO   60      1256.101627216914882057         0.000000000000000000      125610.1627216914785095 0x4deb0033bb26bc534b197e61d19e0733e5679784
child DAO   61        15.276059789372406985         0.000000000000000000        1527.6059789372407067 0x35a051a0010aba705c9008d7a7eff6fb88f6ea7b
child DAO   62       934.889382511061152962         0.000000000000000000       93488.9382511061121477 0x9da397b9e80755301a3b32173283a91c0ef6c87e
child DAO   63         0.384900000000000000         0.000000000000000000       55938.4955979606020264 0x0101f3be8ebb4bbd39a2e3b9a3639d4259832fd9
child DAO   64         0.000000000124360133         0.000000000000000000     3069680.3822257122956216 0xbcf899e6c7d9d5a215ab1e3444c86806fa854c76
child DAO   65         5.000006477258637377         0.000000000000000000         500.0006477258637574 0xa2f1ccba9395d7fcb155bba8bc92db9bafaeade7
child DAO   66      1000.001295451727475566         0.000000000000000000      100000.1295451727492036 0xd164b088bd9108b60d0ca3751da4bceb207b0782
child DAO   67         0.068587370259945226         0.000000000000000000           6.8587370259945226 0x1cba23d343a983e9b5cfd19496b9a9701ada385f
child DAO   68      1409.336722195117395464         0.000000000000000000      140933.6722195117617957 0x9fcd2deaff372a39cc679d5c5e4de7bafb0b1339
child DAO   69     19173.240336954131945545       118.886510785155274580     1917324.0336954134982079 0x0e0da70933f4c7849fc0d203f5d1d43b9ae4532d
child DAO   70      5634.097608979247392143         0.000000000000000000      563409.7608979246579111 0xbc07118b9ac290e4622f5e77a0853539789effbe
child DAO   71       207.153967008322399135         0.000000000000000000       20715.3967008322397305 0xacd87e28b0c9d1254e868b81cba4cc20d9a32225
child DAO   73      6773.243673260677597543         0.000000000000000000      677324.3673260677605867 0x5524c55fb03cf21f549444ccbecb664d0acad706
Baddies     74       269.833661813680507459         0.000000000000000000       26982.3661813680519117 0xfe24cdd8648121a43a7c86d289be4dd2951ed49f
child DAO   76         3.486036451558542464         0.000000000000000000         348.6036451558542240 0x253488078a4edf4d6f42f113d1e62836a942cf1a
Goodies     78   7277385.711515429122911683         0.000000000000000000   727738571.1515429019927979 0xb136707642a4ea12fb4bae820f03d2562ebff487
Baddies     81         2.123311222366559138         0.000000000000000000         212.3311222366559150 0xf14c14075d6c4ed84b86798af0956deef67365b5
child DAO   85       859.189750496835322093         0.000000000000000000       85918.9750496835331433 0xaeeb8ff27288bdabc0fa5ebb731b6f409507516c
child DAO   87         1.944767821345229848         0.000000000000000000         194.4767821345229777 0x6d87578288b6cb5549d5076a207456a1f6a63dc0
child DAO   94        23.997787866533545896         0.000000000000000000        2399.7787866533544729 0xaccc230e8a6e5be9160b8cdf2864dd2a001c28b6
Baddies     98     28927.603152430302650042      5192.307692307692307692     2892760.3152430304326117 0x4613f3bca5c44ea06337a9e439fbc6d42e501d0a
Goodies     99    598974.326560793095813484     73722.042576599901129491    59897432.6560793146491051 0x84ef4b2357079cd7a7c69fd7a37cd0609a679106
child DAO  101         0.000000000000000021       369.231179004682274248    26956559.1797974072396755 0xf4c64518ea10f995918a454158c6b61407ea345c
---------- --- ---------------------------- ---------------------------- ---------------------------- ------------------------------------------
Total      289   7945651.899439196102321148     79689.629520730901276693  2353135147.8047966957092285      Balance%     ExtraBal%       Tokens%
---------- --- ---------------------------- ---------------------------- ---------------------------- ------------------------------------------
Baddies            29199.560125466348836198      5478.021988021978359029   367160807.7738258838653564    0.3674911%    6.8741968%   15.6030480%
Goodies          7876360.038076222874224186     73722.042576599895255640   787636003.8076221942901611   99.1279273%   92.5114636%   33.4717708%
Maybies            40029.123080715187825263       489.564956108944272728    44521737.5208813324570656    0.5037865%    0.6143396%    1.8920179%
---------- --- ---------------------------- ---------------------------- ---------------------------- ------------------------------------------
```

**NOTE that the baddies have drained 3641694.241898506992612606 ETH from child DAO #59**

**UPDATE 09:24 02/08/2016 GMT** - [What's happening within child DAO #59 on the ETC chain?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7673/whats-happening-within-child-dao-59-on-the-etc-chain)

The balance from child DAO #59 has been moved by child DAO Proposal #10 into [0x10abb5efecdc09581f8b7cb95791fe2936790b4e](http://gastracker.io/addr/0x10abb5efecdc09581f8b7cb95791fe2936790b4e) that has an amount of 3642408.52761279270689932 ETC.

This is a grand child DAO that shares the same code as the original The DAO.

The same account has a balance on the ETH chain - [0x10abb5efecdc09581f8b7cb95791fe2936790b4e](https://etherscan.io/address/0x10abb5efecdc09581f8b7cb95791fe2936790b4e). Noticed by @DaxClassix on reddit.

From [2xC19LBZ](https://www.reddit.com/user/2xC19LBZ) on reddit:

> 38K ETH accidentally sent to TheDAO after fork, were finally moved to this address. That's why this address does have 38K ETH now on forked chain.

---

From comparison, here is the data with child DAO #59 generated from the ETH pre hard-fork @ Jun 26 at 13:33 GMT, with the full data available in [How many ethers have been drained through the recursive call attacks on The DAO?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6408/how-many-ethers-have-been-drained-through-the-recursive-call-attacks-on-the-dao):

```
Type         #                      Balance                 ExtraBalance                       Tokens Address
---------- --- ---------------------------- ---------------------------- ---------------------------- ------------------------------------------
Baddies     59   3641694.241898506992612617         0.000010000000000000   364169424.1898506879806519 0x304a554a310c7e546dfe434669c62820b7d83490
```

And here is the data generated from the ETH chain @ 06:05 02/08/2016 GMT:

```
Type         #                      Balance                 ExtraBalance                       Tokens Address
---------- --- ---------------------------- ---------------------------- ---------------------------- ------------------------------------------
The DAO      0         0.000000000000000004         0.000000000000000000  1153816598.7024669647216797 0xbb9bc244d798123fde783fcc1c72d3bb8c189413
child DAO    1         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000          11.0000142499690430 0xd4fe7bc31cedb7bfb8a345f31e668033056b2728
child DAO    4         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000          79.8519214441755594 0x2c19c7f9ae8b751e37aeb2d93a699722395ae18f
child DAO    7         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000       98900.1281201758538373 0x1975bd06d486162d5dc297798dfc41edd5d160a7
child DAO    8         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000      202867.2384762869332917 0x319f70bab6845585f412ec7724b744fec6095c85
child DAO   10         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000       20500.6432347392910742 0x5c8536898fbb74fc7445814902fd08422eac56d0
child DAO   13         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000      105482.6948358116351301 0x779543a0491a837ca36ce8c635d6154e3c4911a6
child DAO   14         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000       74635.9658653056685580 0x5c6e67ccd5849c0d29219c4f95f1a7a93b3f5dc5
child DAO   16         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000      125000.1619314659328666 0x200450f06520bdd6c527622a273333384d870efb
child DAO   18         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000     3457503.6590232858434319 0x6b0c4d41ba9ab8d8cfb5d379c69a612f2ced8ecb
child DAO   19         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000     1686497.8387737083248794 0xd1ac8b1ef1b69ff51d1d401a476e7e612414f091
child DAO   20         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000        1000.0012954517275148 0x51e0ddd9998364a2eb38588679f0d2c42653e4a6
child DAO   22         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000      240000.3009084016666748 0xf0b1aa0eb660754448a7937c022e30aa692fe0c5
child DAO   23         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000        9999.8647723253125150 0x9f27daea7aca0aa0446220b98d028715e3bc803d
child DAO   26         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000       10000.0129545172749204 0xd9aef3a1e38a39c16b31d1ace71bca8ef58d315b
child DAO   27         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000        4117.3345768012804911 0x6f6704e5a10332af6672e50b3d9754dc460dfa4d
child DAO   28         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000       36738.0383063135377597 0x492ea3bb0f3315521c31f273e565b868fc090f17
child DAO   29         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000     1583946.1690131428185850 0x9ea779f907f0b315b364b0cfc39a0fde5b02a416
child DAO   31         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000           6.0000077727103651 0xcc34673c6c40e791051898567a1222daf90be287
child DAO   32         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000       10705.0138678107414307 0xe308bd1ac5fda103967359b2712dd89deffb7973
child DAO   33         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000     1313899.0176146971061826 0xac1ecab32727358dba8962a0f3b261731aad9723
child DAO   34         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000       26685.4104538362880703 0x440c59b325d2997a134c2c7c60a8c61611212bad
child DAO   35         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000         223.6999142516500854 0x9c15b54878ba618f494b38f0ae7443db6af648ba
child DAO   36         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000           2.7428797178668631 0x21c7fdb9ed8d291d79ffd82eb2c4356ec0d81241
child DAO   37         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000        7676.1842290232380037 0x1ca6abd14d30affe533b24d7a21bff4c2d5e1f3b
child DAO   39         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000      212183.7249362469301559 0x6131c42fa982e56929107413a9d526fd99405560
child DAO   41         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000     1254878.3143344640266150 0x542a9515200d14b68e934e9830d91645a980dd7a
child DAO   44         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000       25000.0323862931873009 0x782495b7b3355efb2833d56ecb34dc22ad7dfcc4
child DAO   45         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000           0.0000000000000001 0x3ba4d81db016dc2890c81f3acec2454bff5aada5
child DAO   52         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000         500.0006477258637574 0xe4ae1efdfc53b73893af49113d8694a057b9c0d1
child DAO   53         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000         714.4077587762826624 0x0737a6b837f97f46ebade41b9bc3e1c509c85c53
child DAO   54         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000      199600.2585721648065373 0x52c5317c848ba20c7504cb2c8052abd1fde29d03
child DAO   56         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000         500.0006477258637574 0x5d2b2e6fcbe3b11d26b525e085ff818dae332479
child DAO   57         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000           0.9900012824972102 0x057b56736d32b86616a10f619859c6cd6f59092a
Baddies     59         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000   364240852.7612792849540710 0x304a554a310c7e546dfe434669c62820b7d83490
child DAO   60         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000      125610.1627216914785095 0x4deb0033bb26bc534b197e61d19e0733e5679784
child DAO   61         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000        1527.6059789372407067 0x35a051a0010aba705c9008d7a7eff6fb88f6ea7b
child DAO   62         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000       93488.9382511061121477 0x9da397b9e80755301a3b32173283a91c0ef6c87e
child DAO   63         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000       55938.4955979606020264 0x0101f3be8ebb4bbd39a2e3b9a3639d4259832fd9
child DAO   64         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000     3069680.3822257122956216 0xbcf899e6c7d9d5a215ab1e3444c86806fa854c76
child DAO   65         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000         500.0006477258637574 0xa2f1ccba9395d7fcb155bba8bc92db9bafaeade7
child DAO   66         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000      100000.1295451727492036 0xd164b088bd9108b60d0ca3751da4bceb207b0782
child DAO   67         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000           6.8587370259945226 0x1cba23d343a983e9b5cfd19496b9a9701ada385f
child DAO   68         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000      140933.6722195117617957 0x9fcd2deaff372a39cc679d5c5e4de7bafb0b1339
child DAO   69         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000     1917324.0336954134982079 0x0e0da70933f4c7849fc0d203f5d1d43b9ae4532d
child DAO   70         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000      563409.7608979246579111 0xbc07118b9ac290e4622f5e77a0853539789effbe
child DAO   71         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000       20715.3967008322397305 0xacd87e28b0c9d1254e868b81cba4cc20d9a32225
child DAO   73         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000      677324.3673260677605867 0x5524c55fb03cf21f549444ccbecb664d0acad706
Baddies     74         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000       26982.3661813680519117 0xfe24cdd8648121a43a7c86d289be4dd2951ed49f
child DAO   76         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000         348.6036451558542240 0x253488078a4edf4d6f42f113d1e62836a942cf1a
Goodies     78         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000   727738571.1515429019927979 0xb136707642a4ea12fb4bae820f03d2562ebff487
Baddies     81         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000         212.3311222366559150 0xf14c14075d6c4ed84b86798af0956deef67365b5
child DAO   85         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000       85918.9750496835331433 0xaeeb8ff27288bdabc0fa5ebb731b6f409507516c
child DAO   87         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000         194.4767821345229777 0x6d87578288b6cb5549d5076a207456a1f6a63dc0
child DAO   94         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000        2399.7787866533544729 0xaccc230e8a6e5be9160b8cdf2864dd2a001c28b6
Baddies     98         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000     2892760.3152430304326117 0x4613f3bca5c44ea06337a9e439fbc6d42e501d0a
Goodies     99         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000    59897432.6560793146491051 0x84ef4b2357079cd7a7c69fd7a37cd0609a679106
child DAO  101         0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000    26956559.1797974072396755 0xf4c64518ea10f995918a454158c6b61407ea345c
child DAO  272     38353.864815688889001225         0.000000000000000000     3835386.4815688887611032 0x10abb5efecdc09581f8b7cb95791fe2936790b4e
child DAO  273        98.123341111110998772         0.000000000000000000        9812.3341111110985366 0x39771e2d34eda36a49ff4fa4194d7fcb839165da
---------- --- ---------------------------- ---------------------------- ---------------------------- ------------------------------------------
Total      287     38451.988156799998250790         0.000000000000000000  2356980346.6204767227172852      Balance%     ExtraBal%       Tokens%
---------- --- ---------------------------- ---------------------------- ---------------------------- ------------------------------------------
Baddies                0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000   367160807.7738258838653564    0.0000000%                 15.5775931%
Goodies                0.000000000000000000         0.000000000000000000   787636003.8076221942901611    0.0000000%                 33.4171647%
Maybies            38451.988156799998250790         0.000000000000000000    48366936.3365613296627998  100.0000000%                  2.0520721%
---------- --- ---------------------------- ---------------------------- ---------------------------- ------------------------------------------
```