# What's happening within child DAO #59 on the ETC chain?

Tags: the-dao, attacks, hardforks, balances, ethereum-classic

From [What are the balances of The DAO and it's child DAOs on the Ethereum Classic chain?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7668/what-are-the-balances-of-the-dao-and-its-child-daos-on-the-ethereum-classic-cha) we know that the baddies have drained 3641694.241898506992612606 ETH from child DAO #59.

What is happening within child DAO #59?

See also:

- [What are the balances of The DAO and it's child DAOs on the Ethereum Classic chain?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7668/what-are-the-balances-of-the-dao-and-its-child-daos-on-the-ethereum-classic-cha)
- [How many ethers have been drained through the recursive call attacks on The DAO?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6408/how-many-ethers-have-been-drained-through-the-recursive-call-attacks-on-the-dao)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Summary

The balance from child DAO #59 has been moved by child DAO Proposal #10 into grand child DAO [0x10abb5efecdc09581f8b7cb95791fe2936790b4e](http://gastracker.io/addr/0x10abb5efecdc09581f8b7cb95791fe2936790b4e) that has an amount of 3642408.52761279270689932 ETC.

Here's are the details for Proposal #10:

```
--- ChildDAO Proposal 10 ---
  Proposal Id         : 10
  Recipient           : 0xbe3ae5cb97c253dda67181c6e34e43f5c275e08b
  Amount              : 0
  Description         : 
  Voting deadlne      : 1469072096 Thu, 21 Jul 2016 13:34:56 AEST
  Open                : true
  Passed              : true
  Deposit             : 0
  New curator         : true (Split)
  Yea                 : 1e-16
  Nay                 : 0
  Creator             : 0x7498bb5749c9801f1f7e490baf5f966dbfe4e97b
  Address             : 0x10abb5efecdc09581f8b7cb95791fe2936790b4e
  Balance             : 3642408.52761279270689932
  ExtraBalance Account: 0xfde8d5f77ef48bb7bf5766c7404691b9ee1dfca7
  ExtraBalance        : 0
  Supply              : 364240852.7612793
  #Proposals          : 0
```

The grand child DAO has the same code as The DAO (Thanks [w2qw](https://www.reddit.com/user/w2qw) on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/4vr4om/the_baddies_have_moved_3641694241898506992612617/)).

[@DaxClassix](https://www.reddit.com/user/DaxClassix) on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/4vrmls/child_dao_59_balance_364240852761279270689932_etc/) noticed that there is a balance on the main chain [0x10abb5efecdc09581f8b7cb95791fe2936790b4e](https://etherscan.io/address/0x10abb5efecdc09581f8b7cb95791fe2936790b4e).

The contract address was created pre-fork - https://etherscan.io/txsInternal?a=0x10abb5efecdc09581f8b7cb95791fe2936790b4e&p=12.

From [2xC19LBZ](https://www.reddit.com/user/2xC19LBZ) on reddit:

> 38K ETH accidentally sent to TheDAO after fork, were finally moved to this address. That's why this address does have 38K ETH now on forked chain.

---

### Details

Here is the script I used to query the ETC blockchain:

```
#!/bin/sh
# 
# Copyright (c) 2016 BokkyPooBah.
# 
# Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of
# this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in 
# the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to 
# use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies 
# of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do 
# so, subject to the following conditions:
# 
# The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all
# copies or substantial portions of the Software.
# 
# THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR 
# IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS
# FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR
# COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER
# IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN
# CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
# 

geth attach << EOF | grep "DATA" | sed "s/^DATA: //"

function printProposal(proposalId, proposal, spaces) {
  var recipient = proposal[0];
  var amount = proposal[1];
  var description = proposal[2];
  var votingDeadline = proposal[3];
  var open = proposal[4];
  var proposalPassed = proposal[5];
  var proposalDeposit = web3.fromWei(proposal[7], "ether");
  var newCurator = proposal[8];
  var yea = proposal[9] / 1e16;
  var nay = proposal[10] / 1e16;
  var creator = proposal[11];
  console.log("DATA: " + spaces + "Proposal Id         : " + proposalId);
  console.log("DATA: " + spaces + "Recipient           : " + recipient);
  console.log("DATA: " + spaces + "Amount              : " + amount);
  console.log("DATA: " + spaces + "Description         : " + description);
  console.log("DATA: " + spaces + "Voting deadlne      : " + votingDeadline + " " + new Date(votingDeadline * 1000));
  console.log("DATA: " + spaces + "Open                : " + open);
  console.log("DATA: " + spaces + "Passed              : " + proposalPassed);
  console.log("DATA: " + spaces + "Deposit             : " + proposalDeposit);
  console.log("DATA: " + spaces + "New curator         : " + newCurator + " " + (newCurator ? "(Split)" : "(Non-Split)"));
  console.log("DATA: " + spaces + "Yea                 : " + yea);
  console.log("DATA: " + spaces + "Nay                 : " + nay);
  console.log("DATA: " + spaces + "Creator             : " + creator);
}

function chaseTheChildDAO(proposalId) {
  var theDAOAddress="0xbb9bc244d798123fde783fcc1c72d3bb8c189413";
  var theDAOABI =[{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"proposals","outputs":[{"name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"name":"amount","type":"uint256"},{"name":"description","type":"string"},{"name":"votingDeadline","type":"uint256"},{"name":"open","type":"bool"},{"name":"proposalPassed","type":"bool"},{"name":"proposalHash","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"proposalDeposit","type":"uint256"},{"name":"newCurator","type":"bool"},{"name":"yea","type":"uint256"},{"name":"nay","type":"uint256"},{"name":"creator","type":"address"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"name":"_amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"minTokensToCreate","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"rewardAccount","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"daoCreator","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"divisor","outputs":[{"name":"divisor","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"extraBalance","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_proposalID","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_transactionData","type":"bytes"}],"name":"executeProposal","outputs":[{"name":"_success","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"unblockMe","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalRewardToken","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"actualBalance","outputs":[{"name":"_actualBalance","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"closingTime","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"allowedRecipients","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferWithoutReward","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"refund","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_recipient","type":"address"},{"name":"_amount","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_description","type":"string"},{"name":"_transactionData","type":"bytes"},{"name":"_debatingPeriod","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_newCurator","type":"bool"}],"name":"newProposal","outputs":[{"name":"_proposalID","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"DAOpaidOut","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"minQuorumDivisor","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_newContract","type":"address"}],"name":"newContract","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"balance","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_recipient","type":"address"},{"name":"_allowed","type":"bool"}],"name":"changeAllowedRecipients","outputs":[{"name":"_success","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"halveMinQuorum","outputs":[{"name":"_success","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"paidOut","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_proposalID","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_newCurator","type":"address"}],"name":"splitDAO","outputs":[{"name":"_success","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"DAOrewardAccount","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"proposalDeposit","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"numberOfProposals","outputs":[{"name":"_numberOfProposals","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"lastTimeMinQuorumMet","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_toMembers","type":"bool"}],"name":"retrieveDAOReward","outputs":[{"name":"_success","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"receiveEther","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"isFueled","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_tokenHolder","type":"address"}],"name":"createTokenProxy","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_proposalID","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getNewDAOAddress","outputs":[{"name":"_newDAO","type":"address"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_proposalID","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_supportsProposal","type":"bool"}],"name":"vote","outputs":[{"name":"_voteID","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"getMyReward","outputs":[{"name":"_success","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"rewardToken","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFromWithoutReward","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"},{"name":"_spender","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"name":"remaining","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_proposalDeposit","type":"uint256"}],"name":"changeProposalDeposit","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"blocked","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"curator","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_proposalID","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_recipient","type":"address"},{"name":"_amount","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_transactionData","type":"bytes"}],"name":"checkProposalCode","outputs":[{"name":"_codeChecksOut","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"privateCreation","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"_curator","type":"address"},{"name":"_daoCreator","type":"address"},{"name":"_proposalDeposit","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_minTokensToCreate","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_closingTime","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_privateCreation","type":"address"}],"type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"_amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"_owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"_amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"FuelingToDate","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"CreatedToken","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Refund","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"proposalID","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"amount","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"newCurator","type":"bool"},{"indexed":false,"name":"description","type":"string"}],"name":"ProposalAdded","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"proposalID","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"position","type":"bool"},{"indexed":true,"name":"voter","type":"address"}],"name":"Voted","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"proposalID","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"result","type":"bool"},{"indexed":false,"name":"quorum","type":"uint256"}],"name":"ProposalTallied","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"_newCurator","type":"address"}],"name":"NewCurator","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"_recipient","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"_allowed","type":"bool"}],"name":"AllowedRecipientChanged","type":"event"}];
  var theDAO = web3.eth.contract(theDAOABI).at(theDAOAddress);
  var numberOfProposals = theDAO.numberOfProposals();
  var proposal = theDAO.proposals(proposalId);  
  printProposal(proposalId, proposal, "");

  var childDAOAddress = theDAO.getNewDAOAddress(proposalId);
  console.log("DATA: Address             : " + childDAOAddress);
  var childDAO = web3.eth.contract(theDAOABI).at(childDAOAddress);
  var childDAOBalance = web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(childDAOAddress), "ether");
  console.log("DATA: Balance             : " + childDAOBalance);
  var childDAOExtraBalanceAccount = childDAO.extraBalance();
  console.log("DATA: ExtraBalance Account: " + childDAOExtraBalanceAccount);
  var childDAOExtraBalance = web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(childDAOExtraBalanceAccount), "ether");
  console.log("DATA: ExtraBalance        : " + childDAOExtraBalance);
  var childDAOTotalSupply = childDAO.totalSupply()/1e16;
  console.log("DATA: Supply              : " + childDAOTotalSupply);
  var childDAONumberOfProposals = childDAO.numberOfProposals();
  console.log("DATA: #Proposals          : " + childDAONumberOfProposals);
  var i;
  for (i=1; i<=childDAONumberOfProposals; i++) {
    console.log("DATA: --- ChildDAO Proposal " + i + " ---");
    var childDAOProposal = childDAO.proposals(i);
    printProposal(i, childDAOProposal, "  ");
    var childChildDAOAddress = childDAO.getNewDAOAddress(i);
    if (childChildDAOAddress != "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000") {
    console.log("DATA:   Address             : " + childChildDAOAddress);
    var childChildDAO = web3.eth.contract(theDAOABI).at(childChildDAOAddress);
    var childChildDAOBalance = web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(childChildDAOAddress), "ether");
    console.log("DATA:   Balance             : " + childChildDAOBalance);
    var childChildDAOExtraBalanceAccount = childChildDAO.extraBalance();
    console.log("DATA:   ExtraBalance Account: " + childChildDAOExtraBalanceAccount);
    var childChildDAOExtraBalance = web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(childChildDAOExtraBalanceAccount), "ether");
    console.log("DATA:   ExtraBalance        : " + childChildDAOExtraBalance);
    var childChildDAOTotalSupply = childChildDAO.totalSupply()/1e16;
    console.log("DATA:   Supply              : " + childChildDAOTotalSupply);
    var childChildDAONumberOfProposals = childChildDAO.numberOfProposals();
    console.log("DATA:   #Proposals          : " + childChildDAONumberOfProposals);
    }
  }
}

chaseTheChildDAO(59);
console.log("DATA: Report generated at " + new Date());

exit;

EOF
```

And here is the generated data:

```
Proposal Id         : 59
Recipient           : 0xb656b2a9c3b2416437a811e07466ca712f5a5b5a
Amount              : 0
Description         : lonely, so lonely
Voting deadlne      : 1465969081 Wed, 15 Jun 2016 15:38:01 AEST
Open                : false
Passed              : true
Deposit             : 0
New curator         : true (Split)
Yea                 : 2e-16
Nay                 : 3838629.9999999995
Creator             : 0xb656b2a9c3b2416437a811e07466ca712f5a5b5a
Address             : 0x304a554a310c7e546dfe434669c62820b7d83490
Balance             : 1.1e-17
ExtraBalance Account: 0x914d1b8b43e92723e64fd0a06f5bdb8dd9b10c79
ExtraBalance        : 285.714295714285714286
Supply              : 364240852.7612793
#Proposals          : 14
--- ChildDAO Proposal 1 ---
  Proposal Id         : 1
  Recipient           : 0xbe3ae5cb97c253dda67181c6e34e43f5c275e08b
  Amount              : 0
  Description         : 
  Voting deadlne      : 1469072096 Thu, 21 Jul 2016 13:34:56 AEST
  Open                : true
  Passed              : false
  Deposit             : 0
  New curator         : true (Split)
  Yea                 : 1e-16
  Nay                 : 0
  Creator             : 0x7498bb5749c9801f1f7e490baf5f966dbfe4e97b
--- ChildDAO Proposal 2 ---
  Proposal Id         : 2
  Recipient           : 0xbe3ae5cb97c253dda67181c6e34e43f5c275e08b
  Amount              : 0
  Description         : 
  Voting deadlne      : 1469072096 Thu, 21 Jul 2016 13:34:56 AEST
  Open                : true
  Passed              : false
  Deposit             : 0
  New curator         : true (Split)
  Yea                 : 1e-16
  Nay                 : 0
  Creator             : 0x7498bb5749c9801f1f7e490baf5f966dbfe4e97b
--- ChildDAO Proposal 3 ---
  Proposal Id         : 3
  Recipient           : 0xbe3ae5cb97c253dda67181c6e34e43f5c275e08b
  Amount              : 0
  Description         : 
  Voting deadlne      : 1469072096 Thu, 21 Jul 2016 13:34:56 AEST
  Open                : true
  Passed              : false
  Deposit             : 0
  New curator         : true (Split)
  Yea                 : 1e-16
  Nay                 : 0
  Creator             : 0x7498bb5749c9801f1f7e490baf5f966dbfe4e97b
--- ChildDAO Proposal 4 ---
  Proposal Id         : 4
  Recipient           : 0xbe3ae5cb97c253dda67181c6e34e43f5c275e08b
  Amount              : 0
  Description         : 
  Voting deadlne      : 1469072096 Thu, 21 Jul 2016 13:34:56 AEST
  Open                : true
  Passed              : false
  Deposit             : 0
  New curator         : true (Split)
  Yea                 : 1e-16
  Nay                 : 0
  Creator             : 0x7498bb5749c9801f1f7e490baf5f966dbfe4e97b
--- ChildDAO Proposal 5 ---
  Proposal Id         : 5
  Recipient           : 0xbe3ae5cb97c253dda67181c6e34e43f5c275e08b
  Amount              : 0
  Description         : 
  Voting deadlne      : 1469072096 Thu, 21 Jul 2016 13:34:56 AEST
  Open                : true
  Passed              : false
  Deposit             : 0
  New curator         : true (Split)
  Yea                 : 1e-16
  Nay                 : 0
  Creator             : 0x7498bb5749c9801f1f7e490baf5f966dbfe4e97b
--- ChildDAO Proposal 6 ---
  Proposal Id         : 6
  Recipient           : 0xbe3ae5cb97c253dda67181c6e34e43f5c275e08b
  Amount              : 0
  Description         : 
  Voting deadlne      : 1469072096 Thu, 21 Jul 2016 13:34:56 AEST
  Open                : true
  Passed              : false
  Deposit             : 0
  New curator         : true (Split)
  Yea                 : 1e-16
  Nay                 : 0
  Creator             : 0x7498bb5749c9801f1f7e490baf5f966dbfe4e97b
--- ChildDAO Proposal 7 ---
  Proposal Id         : 7
  Recipient           : 0xbe3ae5cb97c253dda67181c6e34e43f5c275e08b
  Amount              : 0
  Description         : 
  Voting deadlne      : 1469072096 Thu, 21 Jul 2016 13:34:56 AEST
  Open                : true
  Passed              : false
  Deposit             : 0
  New curator         : true (Split)
  Yea                 : 1e-16
  Nay                 : 0
  Creator             : 0x7498bb5749c9801f1f7e490baf5f966dbfe4e97b
--- ChildDAO Proposal 8 ---
  Proposal Id         : 8
  Recipient           : 0xbe3ae5cb97c253dda67181c6e34e43f5c275e08b
  Amount              : 0
  Description         : 
  Voting deadlne      : 1469072096 Thu, 21 Jul 2016 13:34:56 AEST
  Open                : true
  Passed              : false
  Deposit             : 0
  New curator         : true (Split)
  Yea                 : 1e-16
  Nay                 : 0
  Creator             : 0x7498bb5749c9801f1f7e490baf5f966dbfe4e97b
--- ChildDAO Proposal 9 ---
  Proposal Id         : 9
  Recipient           : 0xbe3ae5cb97c253dda67181c6e34e43f5c275e08b
  Amount              : 0
  Description         : 
  Voting deadlne      : 1469072096 Thu, 21 Jul 2016 13:34:56 AEST
  Open                : true
  Passed              : false
  Deposit             : 0
  New curator         : true (Split)
  Yea                 : 1e-16
  Nay                 : 0
  Creator             : 0x7498bb5749c9801f1f7e490baf5f966dbfe4e97b
--- ChildDAO Proposal 10 ---
  Proposal Id         : 10
  Recipient           : 0xbe3ae5cb97c253dda67181c6e34e43f5c275e08b
  Amount              : 0
  Description         : 
  Voting deadlne      : 1469072096 Thu, 21 Jul 2016 13:34:56 AEST
  Open                : true
  Passed              : true
  Deposit             : 0
  New curator         : true (Split)
  Yea                 : 1e-16
  Nay                 : 0
  Creator             : 0x7498bb5749c9801f1f7e490baf5f966dbfe4e97b
  Address             : 0x10abb5efecdc09581f8b7cb95791fe2936790b4e
  Balance             : 3642408.52761279270689932
  ExtraBalance Account: 0xfde8d5f77ef48bb7bf5766c7404691b9ee1dfca7
  ExtraBalance        : 0
  Supply              : 364240852.7612793
  #Proposals          : 0
--- ChildDAO Proposal 11 ---
  Proposal Id         : 11
  Recipient           : 0x304a554a310c7e546dfe434669c62820b7d83490
  Amount              : 0
  Description         : Split for great Justice
  Voting deadlne      : 1469072157 Thu, 21 Jul 2016 13:35:57 AEST
  Open                : true
  Passed              : false
  Deposit             : 0
  New curator         : true (Split)
  Yea                 : 0
  Nay                 : 0
  Creator             : 0xac80cba14c08f8a1242ebd0fd45881cfee54b0a2
--- ChildDAO Proposal 12 ---
  Proposal Id         : 12
  Recipient           : 0x304a554a310c7e546dfe434669c62820b7d83490
  Amount              : 3.642408527612792706899331e+24
  Description         : Ending this game would be nice
  Voting deadlne      : 1469677227 Thu, 28 Jul 2016 13:40:27 AEST
  Open                : true
  Passed              : false
  Deposit             : 0
  New curator         : false (Non-Split)
  Yea                 : 0
  Nay                 : 0
  Creator             : 0xac80cba14c08f8a1242ebd0fd45881cfee54b0a2
  Address             : 0x
Report generated at Tue, 02 Aug 2016 19:16:44 AEST
```