# Late to the DAO Withdraw Game

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, dao

So I'm super late withdrawing the DAO and depositing it in my Ethereum Wallet. I tried to withdraw my DAO on one occasion. I created a DOA Watch Contract and a DAO Withdraw Contract. Nothing happened. I had no confirmations on my execution contract and nothing was deposited in my account. Should I have more Ether in my wallet to propel the withdraw? Total novice here. Any advice would be appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: Is DOA a typo of DAO?

Answer (score 1):

You only need about 0.1 ETH in your wallet to properly withdraw.

Here's the guides for all the refunds:

- [How do I convert my The DAO tokens into ethers using the withdrawal contract after the hard fork?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7204/how-do-i-convert-my-the-dao-tokens-into-ethers-using-the-withdrawal-contract-aft)
- [How do I get a refund for the amount I paid in excess of 1 ether to 100 The DAO tokens](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7265/how-do-i-get-a-refund-for-the-amount-i-paid-in-excess-of-1-ether-to-100-the-dao)
- [How do I get a refund for my The DAO tokens that was split into a child DAO?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7299/how-do-i-get-a-refund-for-my-the-dao-tokens-that-was-split-into-a-child-dao)
- [How do I convert my The DAO tokens into ethers on the Ethereum Classic chain?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8338/how-do-i-convert-my-the-dao-tokens-into-ethers-on-the-ethereum-classic-chain)
- [How to conditionally send ethers to another account post-hard-fork to protect yourself from replay attacks](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7396/how-to-conditionally-send-ethers-to-another-account-post-hard-fork-to-protect-yo)